# Removing files under ~5k

Tags: shell-script, inotify

I have 12 directores:

```
/home/imp/hpt/boxes/110.110.2.0/
/home/imp/hpt/boxes/115.115.16.0
/home/imp/hpt/boxes/1.154.10.0/
/home/imp/hpt/boxes/44.100.0.0/
/home/imp/hpt/boxes/46.1.100.0/

/home/imp/hpt/outbound/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.002/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.02c/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.02e/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.06e/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.073/
/home/imp/hpt/outbound.38f/
```

I want to remove files that are under ~5k in each of these directories.
The files are `*.mo?` `*.tu?` `*.we?` `*.th?` `*.fr?` `*.sa?` `*su?` where `?`
is a number from `0` to `9`

I've read about `inotifywait`, and was wondering if it could be used to achieve this. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Edit: Ok, here is a `inotifywait` script i'm trying to write.. I didn't get very far as you can see.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=/home/imp/hpt/boxes/110.110.2.0/
dir2=/home/imp/hpt/boxes/115.115.16.0/
dir3=/home/imp/hpt/boxes/1.54.10.0/
dir4=/home/imp/hpt/boxes/44.100.0.0/
dir5=/home/imp/hpt/boxes/46.1.100.0/
dir6=/home/imp/hpt/outbound/
dir7=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.002/
dir8=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.02c/
dir9=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.02e/
dir10=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.06e/
dir11=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.073/
dir12=/home/imp/hpt/outbound.38f/

inotifywait --daemon --outfile /home/imp/hpt/remove.log -m "$dir1" "$dir2" "$dir3" "$dir4" "$dir5" "$dir6" "$dir7" "$dir8" "$dir10" "$dir11" "$dir12" -e     delete |
    while read path action file; do
        for name in "$dir1'" "$dir2" "$dir3" "$dir4" "$dir5" "$dir6" "$dir7" "$dir8" "$dir9" "$dir10" "$dir11" "$dir12"
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . \( -name '*.mo[0-9]' -o -name '*.tu[0-9]' \) -size -5120c -delete
```

You can use `size -5k`, too, but `find` does some stupid rounding so this is less precise:

> but bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit (so a 1-byte file is not matched by -size -1M)

Comment: ``find ./ -regex ".*mo\.*tu\.*sa[0-9]" -size -5k``

Comment: @RomanGrazhdan I guess you haven't tried that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, what exactly does the `-o` flag do? I need to figure out how to add the rest of the "day" filenames.

Comment: Ok. checked the `find` manpage. I guess `-o` is `OR`

Comment: Ok. Here's the script now: `find . \( -name '*.mo[0-9]' -o -name '*.tu[0-9]' -o -name '*.we[0-9]' -o -name '*.th[0-9]' -o -name '*.fr[0-9]' -o -name '*.sa[0-9]' -o -name '*.su[0-9]' \) -size -5120c -delete` Does that look correct?

Comment: Is it possible to daemonize this process?

Comment: Anyone have a `inotifywait` solution?

Answer (score 0):

`inotify` and `inotifywait` watch for filesystem actions in real-time. You could use them to catch the files as they are created, but they can't help you find files that already exist there.

I'll assume you want to find existing files. With GNU find, the expression to find them could be condensed a bit using a regex pattern:

```
$ find -type f -size -5120c -regextype awk -regex ".*\.(mo|tu|we|th|fr|sa|su)[0-9]" -delete
```

(The size 5120 is in bytes, adjust to what you need.)